# how to get the final score of two parameters while adding?

Tags: php

I want total score of the output.i have written the php program such that score is assigned to each age and waist.For example if i enter the age as 21 then score is 10.similarly if i enter the age as 71 then score is 11 and so on.if I enter the input as 21 and 71 then i should get total as 21.But i am getting total score as 0.

why?

can anyone help.for example

```
 Enter your age:21
 Enter your waist:71
```

after submit the output should like:

```
 the score of age is 10
 the score of waist is 11
 total score is 21.
```

But i am getting

```
 the score of age is 10
 the score of waist is 11
 total score is 0.
```

T2Dsystem.html

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <head>
 <title>DIABETES RISK SCORE SYSTEM</title>
  </head>
 <body bgcolor="lightgreen" text="black" style="font-size:18pt font-family:Garamond"><center>
 <h2>DIABETES RISK SCORE SYSTEM</h2></center>
 <form action="if.php" method="post"> <br/><br/>
 Enter your name:<input type="text" name="fname"pattern="[A-Za-z]+" required /><br> <br>


  <br/>Enter your Gender:<br/><input type="radio" name="fgender"value="female" checked />Female<br>
 <input type=radio name="fgender" value=male>Male</td><br> <br>


 <label for="age">Enter your Age: </label>
<select name="age">
  <option value="">--select the age--</option>
  <option value="21">21</option>
  <option value="22">22</option>
  <option value="23">23</option>
  </select>

 <br/><br/><br/> <label for="fwaist">Enter your Waist in cm's: </label>
 <select name="fwaist">
  <option value="">--select the waist--</option>
  <option value="71">71</option>
  <option value="72">72</option>
  <option value="73">73</option>
  </select>
  <br/><br/><br/><input type="submit"/>
  </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

if.php

```
<html>
 <body>
<?php
 $age = array("21" => 10, "22" => 20, "23" => 30);
  $fwaist = array("71" => 11, "72" => 21, "73" => 31);
  $conn=new mysqli('localhost','root','');
  if($conn->connect_error){
  die("connection failed" .$conn->connect_error);
   }
  echo "\n DB connected successfully";
  mysqli_select_db($conn,"onepage_db");
  echo "\n DB is selected as Test successfully";

   $sql="INSERT INTO onepage_table (fname,fgender,age,fwaist) VALUES('$_POST[fname]','$_POST[fgender]','$_POST[age]','$_POST[fwaist]')";
  if($conn->query($sql)===TRUE){
echo "\n New record created successfully \n";
  } else {
  echo "Error:" .$sql."<br>" .$conn->error;
  }


  if("$_POST[age]"==21)
   {

 echo "\n score of age is ".$age['21']."<br/>";
    }
   elseif("$_POST[age]"==22)
    {
echo "\n the score of age is ".$age['22']."<br/>";
    }
   else
     {

     echo"\n the score of age is ".$age['23']."<br/>";
      }



   if("$_POST[fwaist]"==71)
     {

echo "\n score of waist is ".$fwaist['71']."<br/>";
     }          
    elseif("$_POST[fwaist]"==72)
    {
echo "\n the score of waist is ".$fwaist['72']."<br/>";
   }
    else
   {

     echo"\n the score of waist is ".$fwaist['73']."<br/>";
       }



  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

   $x1 = $_POST["age"];
   $x2 = $_POST["fwaist"];
}


    $total=$x1+$x2;

   echo "\n total score is ",$total;




  mysqli_close($conn);  
  ?>
 </body>
 </html>



i expect the output like 10+11=21 , but the actual output is 0.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your submit input a name

```
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
```

You should also update your PHP to make sure it doesn't cause errors or unexpected behaviour. You have quite a few errors, I made comments so you can see the changes.

```
<html>
 <body>
<?php
 $age = array("21" => 10, "22" => 20, "23" => 30);
 $fwaist = array("71" => 11, "72" => 21, "73" => 31);
$conn=new mysqli('localhost','root','');
if($conn->connect_error){
    die("connection failed" .$conn->connect_error);
}
echo "\n DB connected successfully";
mysqli_select_db($conn,"onepage_db");
echo "\n DB is selected as Test successfully";

$sql="INSERT INTO onepage_table (fname,fgender,age,fwaist) VALUES('{$_POST['fname']}','{$_POST['fgender']}','{$_POST['age']}','{$_POST['fwaist']}')";
// Key needs to be wrapped in quotes, when concating strings with array values like that you need to wrap them in curly brackets {}
if($conn->query($sql)){ // No need to add === TRUE you can simply check like this
    echo "\n New record created successfully \n";
} else {
    echo "Error:" .$sql."<br>" .$conn->error;
}
// anytime you are calling $_POST you should check to see if you have actualyl submitted the form.
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // Check first if present in the array, if not display not found, if found display value.
    if(isset($age[$_POST['age']])){
        echo "\n score of age is ".$age[$_POST['age']]."<br/>";    
    }else{
        echo "\n score of age not found <br/>";
    }
    if(isset($fwaist[$_POST['fwaist']])){
        echo "\n score of waist is ".$fwaist[$_POST['fwaist']]."<br/>";
    }else{
        echo "\n score of waist not found <br/>";
    }
    // calculate total and display
    $total = $age[$_POST['age']] + $fwaist[$_POST['fwaist']];
    echo "\n total score is " . $total;
}

mysqli_close($conn);  
?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No problem, if this answered your questions remember to make it as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard to tell with your example but I'm willing to bet that both those values come back as strings not integers.

Reguardless of if that is the issue or not pretty much before you do anything else after getting values back from user input you want to..

1 - Make sure they exist

```
if (!isset($_POST['age'])) {
  // we don't have an age at all, something is wrong exit here
}
```

2 - Make sure its what you expect it to be sanitize all user input, in this case we can just use [intval](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) to make sure we have an int, if you try to pass something else not a string or int you will get back an error, so make sure you handle that as well.

```
if (is_string($_POST['age']) || is_int($_POST['age'])) {
// your safe
$int_age = intval($_POST['age']);
}
```

Do that for all values then add them.

Comment: once the total value is appered then i should print that total score into databse so that i should again use insert query?

Comment: Yes but please don't ever.. ever.. even in an example directly put $_POST['anything'] into your database query. That is a sure fire way to end up with either a terrible XXS problem or no database at all when you come back because someone dropped it with their input.